# Zombicide: Black Plague! Strategy suggestions for Clovis and Samson

Tags: tactics, zombicide, zombicide-black-plague

I've completed the 11 quests in the base *Zombicide: Black Plague!* box (i.e. 1 necromancer, 1 abomination, no expansions), and I found that Clovis and Samson consistently lagged behind in terms of experience.

The other survivors have easy to identify roles (Ann and Nelly are fast, so have rapid response roles. Baldric and Silas have fire support roles).

My question is, **what roles do Clovis and Samson fulfill that allows them to keep up in terms of experience?**

PS. As a group we try to make sure we level up together, which works well until the orange danger level, where the other survivors shoot up. We also try to compensate by having Clovis and Samson score objectives when they can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Tips for if any survivor is lagging behind

1. Have them score objectives
2. Have them score a lot of kills with dragon bile attacks
3. Restrain the highest experience player from widening the gap. The tips gained for Clovis and Samson below have been gained from *not* using the wizard Baldric, who tends to dominate

### Clovis

- **Role within the team**: close combat expert dealing with damage 1 zombies (walkers, runners, necromancers etc.)
- **Secondary role within the team**: close combat expert dealing with fatties, if he has a hammer (or 2!)
- **Optimal equipment**: double daggers, shield on body
- **Best skills**: +1 free melee action, +1 free combat action. This is not meant to be subtle - just throw more dice!
- **Additional notes**: only give the hammer from the starting equipment to Ann or Nelly, as these are the 2 fastest survivors, so they become a rapid reaction force to early fatties

[image: Clovis ID Card]

### Samson

- **Role within the team**: door breaking tank. Best used for breaking open buildings and taking damage with his iron hide
- **Secondary role within the team**: abomination hunter (if able to get +1 Damage: melee in the red danger level, though this is less important in the base game with just one abomination)
- **Optimal equipment**: axe (for breaking down doors), hammer, plate armour on body
- **Best skills**: +1 die: Combat (more flexible than +1 dice to roll: melee), Barbarian in the vanilla game ("When resolving a Melee Action, the Survivor may substitute the Dice number of the Melee weapon(s) he uses with the number of Zombies standing in the targeted Zone . Skills affecting the dice value, like +1 die: Melee, still apply." - all those dice!) or +1 Damage if Abominations are a problem

[image: Samson ID Card]

Answer (score 2):

Clovis: He was mostly setup for close combat at full, give him an armor and send him to kill, IF you get to find the 2 bustard swords the sword master skill becomes useful and a great add on, if not go for the other one and get a good sword with a dagger and start to kill more dice = more kills

Samson: he is surely a tank, just with iron hide the 3+ armour and a shield and he becomes practically immortal (unless attacked by abominations) in this setup he will have a 2+ save with reroll against everything that is not an abomination, so imagine the numbers you need around 117 walkers or 60 runners or 38 wolfs activated in his square at 1 time in order to kill him (unless the god dice hates you), so you can easily had him eat punches to slow zombies while others can take items and stuff (just in case make sure someone has the ability to heal) and if you get him to red, this setup with barbarian creates full zombie killing machine tank

Comment: In the Wulfsberg expansion the Dwarven Shield (vault weapon) can block abomination attacks, so I find it useful to give to a character with lots of armour+iron hide.